# how to add scroll bar to a text erea

Tags: php, html, scrollbar

i have a text area that  contain many lines i want to add a scroll bar and just show the first 3 lines how to do this ??

can anyone help me ??i had tried all night to get it work but it failed to show the vertical line it just show the 2 arrows without the ability to scroll.

this what i tried  to do

```
 <div style="width:=100%;height:50%; overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">
                <?php print "$blabdisplaylist"; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why dont you use <textarea rows='3'> ?

Comment: because  the "$blabdisplaylist" is a text area within a loop to add many textarea so i do see how to use textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set `overflow-x` to `hidden` and `overflow` to `scroll` as they conflict with each other.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:3em;overflow:auto">
    Content
</div>
```

Bonus: `3em` will set the height to three lines tall.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;height 3em;'></div>
```